# How to fetch the code comments from a stored procedure / function and populate to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to fetch the code comments from a stored procedure / function and populate to a table?

```
/*
Author : Test
Comment : Test
*/
```

I am working on a user defined function by passing either a stored procedure or function as input parameter to read the code history comments and store it in a table. Having the detail in a table to maintain the version notes for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, there are different ways to get the definition, I prefer `sp_helptext` because it's already splitted in lines

```
DECLARE @Objects TABLE(name varchar(100))
DECLARE @Lines TABLE(id int identity, line varchar(maX))

INSERT @Objects
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE Type in ('FN', 'IF', 'P', 'TR', 'TF') 

DECLARE @ObjectName VARCHAR(100)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Objects)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ObjectName = name FROM @Objects

    DELETE @Lines

    INSERT @Lines (line)
    exec sp_helptext @ObjectName

    DECLARE @Linestart INT, @LineEnd INT
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Lines WHERE charindex('/*', line) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Linestart = id
        FROM @Lines WHERE charindex('/*', line) > 0
        ORDER BY id

        SELECT TOP 1 @LineEnd = id
        FROM @Lines WHERE charindex('*/', line) > 0
        ORDER BY id

        DECLARE @comment VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        SELECT @Coment = @coment + char(13) + char(10) + line
        FROM @Lines 
        WHERE id between @LineStart and @lineEnd

        INSERT INTO yourtable (@objectName, @Comment)

        DELETE @Lines WHERE id between @LineStart and @lineEnd
    END


    DELETE @Objects WHERE name = @ObjectName
END
```

Comment: thank you.. this logic is great.. i have to change this according to my need.. but it really came well..

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function/stored procedure to achieve this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION InsertCommentIntoTable
(   
    @Param1 VARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here

    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max)
    SELECT @str = definition  
    FROM sys.sql_modules  
    WHERE object_id = (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.CustOrderHist'));

    --parse @str string value and do your stuffs: @str has the function and stored procedure codes.

    RETURN 0;

END
GO
```

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question, OP asked how to extract the comments, not how to extract the definition.